# How do I prove that there are no more possible ways to draw a nonisomorphic graphs with a specific degree sequence?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

I've been given an exercise for homework about drawing nonisomorphic graphs. To be precise, this is the question: "Draw all nonisomorphic graphs with degree sequence (3,3,3,3,3,3,6). Prove that none was left out!".

I understand how to draw these nonisomorphic graphs, but I don't know how to prove that none were left out. What type of proof is needed to show that there are none left out?

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately your given degree sequence has a distinctive [universal vertex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_vertex) that doesn't affect the disposition of the other vertices. The degree-$6$ vertex must be connected to all the other vertices. This means that any graph of degree sequence $(2,2,2,2,2,2)$ can be turned into a graph of the form you are seeking, $(6,3,3,3,3,3,3),$ by adding one vertex and connecting that to all other vertices, and that the reverse is true; removing the universal vertex of degree $6$ will produce a graph of degree sequence $(2,2,2,2,2,2)$.

Any $2$-regular graph is a set of (one or more) disjoint cycles. Because a $2$-cycle is not possible for a simple graph, the only two graphs possible for $(2,2,2,2,2,2)$ are $C_3\cup C_3$ and $C_6$.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In general this is not an easy problem, but it can have easy instances. For example, for the degree sequence $(1,1,1,3)$ there is a unique vertex of degree $3$. This implies that there must be at least $3$ other vertices, but the degree sequence contains three other $1$ degrees and therefore the $3$ other vertices must be of degree 1 and they must be adjacent to the degree $3$ vertex.

For harder instances there may need to be analysis by cases. For example, you have a degree sequence of $\;(3,3,3,3,3,3,6),\;$ so similarly, there is a unique vertex of degree $6$ and the other $6$ vertices of degree $3$ are adjacent to the degree $6$ vertex. Now remove the degree $6$ vertex and all of its $6$ edges. What is left is $6$ vertices each of degree $2$, but this implies they form disjoint cycles.

Comment: How would this prove that there are no other options left? I have been able to construct two nonisomorphic graphs with degree sequence (3,3,3,3,3,3,6) and I'm fairly certain that those are the only two that exist. But I dont entirely understand how what you're saying would prove that those are the only two possible cases.